# Why is a host sever location displayed differently?

Tags: ip, host, geolocation

I am very new to this field, and would like to get an explanation on the mechanism of the below.

When I check the location of a host server, sometimes they show the location differently.
For example, let's say I [check the location of the server for "https://serverfault.com/"](https://check-host.net/ip-info?host=https://serverfault.com/), they show three different locations - Quebec, California and Chicago.

I would like to know the mechanism behind why this happens.
Is there a method to know the accurate location?

Comment: Of course, none of them are "correct", meaning they do not tell you where Stack Overflow's servers are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no science here. Each of the companies offering the IP based geolocation in your link uses their own database. They clearly do not agree on where 151.101.129.69 is located.

The Maxmind DB entry has it located at (what appears to be) their default location for the USA.

If there is any science at work then (in this case) it is likely being confused by the use of fastly's CDN.

It is possible with some effort to try to determine the location of a server based on IP address but it is easily confused by the use of CDNs etc. You basically have to [follow the packets from multiple source locations](https://www.ivpn.net/privacy-guides/how-to-verify-physical-locations-of-internet-servers/) and work out where you think things really are.

IP based geolocation is snake oil, but it's the best snake oil we have.